# mysqli_free_result() is slow when all the data are not read while using MYSQLI_USE_RESULT

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, mysqli, database-performance

I am using `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`(Unbuffered query) while querying a huge data from the table.
For testing I took a table of 5.6 GB size.
I selected all columns `Select * from test_table`.

If I am not reading any rows with method like `fetch_assoc()` etc. Then try to close the result with `mysqli_free_result()`. It takes 5 to 10 secs to close it.

Sometimes I read required number rows based on available memory. And then I call `mysqli_free_result()` it takes less time when compared with not even one row is read.

So lesser unread rows means lesser time to free results. More unread rows more time to free results.

It's no where documented that this functionality will consume time in best of my knowledge.

Time taken for query is around 0.0008 sec.

Is it bug or is it expected behavior?
For me this sluggishness defeating whole point using `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`.

> MySQL v5.7.21, PHP v7.2.4 used for testing.

Alias of this function are `mysqli_result::free` -- `mysqli_result::close` -- `mysqli_result::free_result` -- `mysqli_free_result`.